# Is there a homeomorphism ?$ ( \mathbb{R}^2, \mathscr{T}_{{\mathbb{R}}^{\text{Eucl}}}) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R}^2, \mathscr{T}_{R}^{c} )$

Tags: general-topology

Given that $\tau_{X}^{c} = \{S ⊂ X:X \setminus S \text{ is finite or countable}\}  \bigcup \emptyset \subset P(X)$

I have stated and proved(didn't post the proof) the following lemmas but am not sure how to proceed.

Lemma 1. If two topological spaces (X,\tau_X) and (Y,\tau_Y) are homeomorphic, then one of them is Hausdorff if and only if the other is.

Lemma 2. Any metric space is Hausdorff.

Comment: What's this second topology?

Comment: I guess from context the finite complement topology? This would also explain the lemmas, as this topology is not Hausdorff.

Comment: Or maybe the product topology of two copies of the finite complement topology? This is also not Hausdorff.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to post the given topology.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the second topology is the countable complement topology on the plane (which is  not Hausdorff, as all non-empty open sets intersect), or the product of the countable complement topology on $\mathbb{R}$ with itself, which is also not Hausdorff (as a product is Hausdorff iff all components are):

Suppose $f$ would be a homeomorphism. By lemma 2, the first space (the Euclidean topology on the plane) is Hausdorff. By the first lemma, the second space would also be Hausdorff, but this is not the case. Contradiction. So there is no such homeomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Note that in the finite complement topology on the real line, there do not exist two disjoint nonempty open sets.